# How to check if data already exists in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php code. How to check if this 3 parameters (user,agwera,vis) exist in MySQL with PHP? And if already exist don't add a second time. + want `echo "Already in Exists<br/>";`

```
    <?
sleep(10);
define ('DBHOST', 'yyy');
define ('DBNAME', 'xxxx');
define ('DBUSER', 'xxxx');
define ('DBPASS', 'xxxxx');

mysql_pconnect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS) or die('DB');
mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or die ('USER');
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting (0);
$act = isset($_GET['act']) ? $_GET['act'] : '';
switch($act)
{
case 'send':
$destination = $_POST['adress']; 
$signature = $_POST['text']; 
$text = "$signature ";



if (empty($_POST["text"])  or strlen($_POST["text"])==0){

@header("location:error5.php");
break;

}

$str = $_POST['text']; 
if (strlen($str)>160){
@header("location:error4.php");
break;

}

if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{9}$/',$destination))
{
@header("location:error1.php");
break;
}

$str2 = $_POST['sender'];
if (strlen($str2)>11){
@header("location:error2.php");
break;
}

if (empty($_POST["sender"])  or strlen($_POST["sender"])==0){

@header("location:error3.php");
break;

}

else
{

    $password = 'zzzzzz';
    $destination = $_POST['adress']; 
  $nomeri = "995$destination";
    $nomeri2 = $_POST['sender']; 
    $source = $nomeri2;
    $signature = $_POST['text']; 
    $text = "$signature "; 

    $content = 
                'key='.rawurlencode($password). 
                '&destination='.rawurlencode($nomeri). 
                '&sender='.rawurlencode($source). 
                '&content='.rawurlencode($text); 

    $a = file_get_contents('http://example.com/api/send.aspx?'.$content); 

@header("location:ok.php");

mysql_query("INSERT `gagzavnili` SET
                      `user`        =   '".$source."',
                      `agwera`      =   '".$text."',
                      `vis`     =   '".$destination."',
                      `time_upload` =   '".time()."',
                      `time`        =   '".time()."'") or die(mysql_error());
                       $file_id = mysql_insert_id();



}
}
?>
```

Comment: write a select query to find the rows with values (user,agwera,vis) and check if the number of rows of the resulted set and if it is greater than 0 then it means already exists. And see some tutorials

Comment: You want to look at `INSERT IGNORE`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array('user', 'agwera', 'vis');

foreach( $data as $val ) {
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = '$val'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);

if( $count > 0 ) {
    echo "<script>alert('Already Exists')</script>";
} else {
    //insert query for $val...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's June 2014, you shouldn't be using the mysql* lib anymore. Switch to mysqli.

Second, there is no truly elegant way to do this without making two queries.

Run a query to select the row with the parameters you specified. Something along the lines of

```
SELECT COUNT(<some field>) FROM <table name> WHERE field1 = 'value' AND...
```

If count comes back greater than zero, the entry exists. This doesn't just go for PHP, but for any time you want to see if data exists in a database (in your case MySQL).